# PLSQL Granted privilege to user, but still unable to modify data

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I have two schemas, and one schema needs to modify data in the other schema. To facilitate this, I have granted privileges to the table as SYSDBA:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT ON schema1.mytable TO schema2;
EXIT;
```

This returns the message `Grant succeeded.`

However, when schema2 tries to do an update on schema1, I get a permissions error telling me that I do not have the privileges to do an update. I took a look at the **grants** tab in `mytable` in SQLPLUS, and it apparently shows that I don't have privileges:

```
PRIVILEGE   GRANTEE  GRANTABLE    GRANTOR    OBJECT_NAME
INSERT       schema2    No         schema1     mytable
UPDATE       schema2    No         schema1     mytable
SELECT       schema2    No         schema1     mytable
DELETE       schema2    No         schema1     mytable
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some other error. Schema2 does have permissions on schema1.mytable -- just not the permission to "regrant" these permissions to someone else.

Comment: You are probably right.. I misunderstood what 'Grantable' meant.